# Looking a good book about Fourier Series

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm studying Rudin's Mathematical Analysis, but I'd like to study another book (specially the Fourier Series topics) to improve my knowledge. Could you give any suggestions?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell at what depth you want to study Fourier series (feel free to add those details to your question and I will edit accordingly), but for an elementary treatment with some context in applied problems, see *Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems* by Churchill and Brown.

At a deeper level, try *Fourier Series and Orthogonal Functions* by H. Davis (Dover book) and *An Introduction to Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Series* by H. Wilcox (also Dover).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend *[Fourier Series and Integrals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122264517)* by Dym and McKean. It is a very readable introduction to the subject.